# Why does CFSchedule fail with a null pointer error

Tags: coldfusion, scheduled-tasks

I am running CFSchedule to get my scheduled task added to the admin and no matter what I do it keeps coming back with the message "The system has attempted to use an undefined value, which usually indicates a programming error, either in your code or some system code.
Null Pointers are another name for undefined values." I thought this was working code, and no matter what I do I can't figure it out. Here is my code, can someone tell me what I'm missing?

```
<cfschedule action="update"
    task="LoadTeeTimes" 
    operation="HTTPRequest"
    url="https://xxxxxxxxxx.com/Admin/AdminTeeTimesFunction.cfm"
    startDate="4/1/2021"
    endDate="11/30/2021"
    startTime="4:30 AM" 
    endTime="9:30 PM"
    interval="3600" 
    resolveURL="No"
    publish="No"
    result="res">
```

Comment: Strictly a guess but it might be your date format.

Comment: Works with CF2018 over http.  Can you invoke the URL in a browser? Also, check the logs for any additional details about the error (exception.log, scheduler.log, etc...)?

Comment: I can use the real URL directly without problem and I have used that date format previously without an issue. What seems odd to me is that the error implies that some data value I am sending is bad, yet all my values are simple, hard coded parameters.

Comment: Yes, odd... what do the various logs say? Anything further about the. NPE?

Comment: I don't have access to the logs as they are at the hosting company. They informed me that there was some corruption in the server's scheduled task files and they had to recover them from a backup. I can only assume that was the underlying problem. But it sure is an odd result.

Comment: Did restoring the backups finally resolve the error?

Comment: The scheduled tasks started running again after they restored the backups, so I didn't need to run my code to recreate them. Bottom line is I can't be 100% sure, but I think that was why it failed.